# Merge .png images from external url

Tags: php, image, merge, external-url

I have two .php files, which generates two different images.

> modules/generatePNG/generatePNG.php?text=Hello1
>   modules/generateQR/_QR_GENERATOR.php?text=Hello2

I want to merge these generated images without saving (download) files.
Any idea how to merge files?

Thanks.

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  Try reading the [manual page for `imagecopymerge()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopymerge.php).